# How to add course completions to user profiles using API for users that have allowed sharing

Tags: linkedin-api

Working on adding course completion information to users that have authorized our system to write to their profile.  Looking at the LinkedIn API, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/ it looks this is possible if granted the w_compliance authorization but it doesn't seem to be available in the application setup.

I have been trying to contact developer support email provided but have had no response in the last week.  Is there a path or setting that I am not seeing?

How does one get an authentication grant that includes the ability to update user profile course information?